# Efficient way to group by a given list based on a key and collect in same list java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have the below class:

```
class A{
  String property1;
  String property2;
  Double property3;
  Double property4;
}
```

So the property1 and property2 is the key.

```
class Key{
      String property1;
      String property2; 
}
```

I already have a list of A like below:

```
List<A> list=new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to group by using the key and add to another list of A in order to avoid having multiple items with same key in the list:

```
Function<A, Key> keyFunction= r-> Key.valueOf(r.getProperty1(), r.getProperty2());
```

But then while doing group by I have to take a sum of property3 and average of property4.

I need an efficient way to do it.

**Note**: I have skipped the methods of the given classes.

Comment: hows the result suppose to look like? `Map<Key, List<Double>>` where `List<Double>` would contain two values - sum of property3 and average of property4?

Comment: Result should be List<A>, I have to store the results in list only. Just want to make sure that I don't have multiple items in the list with same key that is why I am doing this exercise. I don't want the results as a map. Thanks

Comment: btw there are talks to add `BiCollectorAndThen` in java-12 (I think), that would be suited here too

Comment: You could accept an answer here btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collecting to a `Map` is unavoidable since you want to `group` things. A brute-force way to do that would be :

```
yourListOfA
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             x -> new Key(x.getProperty1(), x.getProperty2()),
             Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                   list -> {
                        double first = list.stream().mapToDouble(A::getProperty3).sum();
                        // or any other default
                        double second = list.stream().mapToDouble(A::getProperty4).average().orElse(0D);
                        A a = list.get(0);
                        return new A(a.getProperty1(), a.getProperty2(), first, second);
            })))
     .values();
```

This could be slightly improved for example in the `Collectors.collectingAndThen` to only iterate the `List` once, for that a custom collector would be required. Not that complicated to write one...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 Map<A,List<A>> map = aList
                     .stream()
                     .collect(Collectors
                             .groupingBy(item->new A(item.property1,item.property2)));

List<A> result= map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(list->new A(list.getValue().get(0).property1,list.getValue().get(0).property1)
                    .avgProperty4(list.getValue())
                    .sumProperty3(list.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and create `avgProperty4` and `sumProperty3` methods like to this

```
public A sumProperty3(List<A> a){
  this.property3 = a.stream().mapToDouble(A::getProperty3).sum();
  return this;
}

public A avgProperty4(List<A> a){
   this.property4 =  a.stream().mapToDouble(A::getProperty4).average().getAsDouble();
   return this;
}
```

---

```
result = aList.stream().collect(Collectors
            .groupingBy(item -> new A(item.property1, item.property2),
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list ->
                            new A(list.get(0).property1, list.get(0).property1)
                                    .avgProperty4(list).sumProperty3(list))
            )
    );
```