# Java stream group by and sum multiple fields

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have a List fooList

```
class Foo {
    private String category;
    private int amount;
    private int price;

    ... constructor, getters & setters
}
```

I would like to group by category and then sum amount aswell as price.

The result will be stored in a map:

```
Map<Foo, List<Foo>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

The key is the Foo holding the summarized amount and price, with a list as value for all the objects with the same category.

So far I've tried the following:

```
Map<String, List<Foo>> map = fooList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Foo::getCategory()));
```

Now I only need to replace the String key with a Foo object holding the summarized amount and price. Here is where I'm stuck. I can't seem to find any way of doing this.

Comment: have you looked at `Collectors.summarizingLong`?

Comment: Yes but how do you summarize on multiple fields?

Comment: well only recently I've answered something very close to this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52041895/1059372 in jdk-12 seems like there will be a `BiCollector` that will make your life easier

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that the KEY shall hold the sums? And that the List<Foo> shall hold all original instances?

Comment: @jokster yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A bit ugly, but it should work:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getCategory))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> {
        int sumAmount = x.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Foo::getAmount).sum();
        int sumPrice= x.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Foo::getPrice).sum();
        return new Foo(x.getKey(), sumAmount, sumPrice);
    }, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: I tried to use your approach but I couldn't solve my issue. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74512927/java-stream-issue-of-calculating-count-sum-of-one-value-and-multiple-group-by-c

Answer (score 9):

My variation of [Sweeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52058989/2513200) uses a reducing Collector instead of streaming twice to sum the individual fields:

```java
Map<Foo, List<Foo>> map = fooList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getCategory))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.reducing(
            (l, r) -> new Foo(l.getCategory(), l.getAmount() + r.getAmount(), l.getPrice() + r.getPrice())))
         .get(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

It is not really *better* though, as it creates a lot of short-lived `Foos`.

Note however that `Foo` is required to provide `hashCode`- and `equals`-implementations that take only `category` into account for the resulting `map` to work correctly. This would probably not be what you want for `Foo`s in general. I would prefer defining a separate `FooSummary` class to contain the aggregated data.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a special, dedicated constructor and `hashCode` and `equals` methods consistently implemented in `Foo` as follows:

```
public Foo(Foo that) { // not a copy constructor!!!
    this.category = that.category;
    this.amount = 0;
    this.price = 0;
}

public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(category);
}

public boolean equals(Object another) {
   if (another == this) return true;
   if (!(another instanceof Foo)) return false;
   Foo that = (Foo) another;
   return Objects.equals(this.category, that.category);
}
```

The `hashCode` and `equals` implementations above allow you to use `Foo` as a meaningful key in the map (otherwise your map would be broken).

Now, with the help of a new method in `Foo` that performs the aggregation of the `amount` and `price` attributes at the same time, you can do what you want in 2 steps. First the method:

```
public void aggregate(Foo that) {
    this.amount += that.amount;
    this.price += that.price;
}
```

Now the final solution:

```
Map<Foo, List<Foo>> result = fooList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::new), // works: special ctor, hashCode & equals
        m -> { m.forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach(k::aggregate)); return m; }));
```

---

EDIT: a few observations were missing...

On one hand, this solution forces you to use an implementation of `hashCode` and `equals` that considers two different `Foo` instances as equal if they belong to the same `category`. Maybe this is not desired, or you already have an implementation that takes more or other attributes into account.

On the other hand, using `Foo` as the key of a map which is used to group instances by one of its attributes is quite an uncommon use case. I think it would be better to just use the `category` attribute to group by category and have two maps: `Map<String, List<Foo>>` to keep the groups and `Map<String, Foo>` to keep the aggregated `price` and `amount`, with the key being the `category` in both cases.

Besides this, this solution mutates the keys of the map after the entries are put into it. This is dangerous, because this could break the map. However, here I'm only mutating attributes of `Foo` that don't participate in neither `hashCode` nor `equals` `Foo`'s implementation. I think that this risk is acceptable in this case, due to the unusuality of the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a helper class, which will hold amount and price

```
final class Pair {
    final int amount;
    final int price;

    Pair(int amount, int price) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

And then just collect list to map:

```
List<Foo> list =//....;

Map<Foo, Pair> categotyPrise = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(foo -> foo,
                    foo -> new Pair(foo.getAmount(), foo.getPrice()),
                    (o, n) -> new Pair(o.amount + n.amount, o.price + n.price)));
```

Comment: that is a good start, but not what the OP needs... read the comments under the question

Answer (score 0):

My take on a solution :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
    foos.add(new Foo("A", 1, 10));
    foos.add(new Foo("A", 2, 10));
    foos.add(new Foo("A", 3, 10));
    foos.add(new Foo("B", 1, 10));
    foos.add(new Foo("C", 1, 10));
    foos.add(new Foo("C", 5, 10));

    List<Foo> summarized = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Foo, List<Foo>> collect = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(new Function<Foo, Foo>() {
        @Override
        public Foo apply(Foo t) {
            Optional<Foo> fOpt = summarized.stream().filter(e -> e.getCategory().equals(t.getCategory())).findFirst();
            Foo f;
            if (!fOpt.isPresent()) {
                f = new Foo(t.getCategory(), 0, 0);
                summarized.add(f);
            } else {
                f = fOpt.get();
            }
            f.setAmount(f.getAmount() + t.getAmount());
            f.setPrice(f.getPrice() + t.getPrice());
            return f;
        }
    }));
    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum like this,

```
ArrayList<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Foo("category_1", 10, 20));
list.add(new Foo("category_2", 11, 21));
list.add(new Foo("category_3", 12, 22));
list.add(new Foo("category_1", 13, 23));
list.add(new Foo("category_2", 14, 24));
list.add(new Foo("category_2", 15, 25));

Map<String, Foo> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getCategory, Function.identity(), (a1, a2) -> {
    a1.joiner(a2);
    return a1;
}));
```

Make sure to add this method to Foo class as well,

```
public Foo joiner(Foo that) {
    this.price += that.price;
    this.amount += that.amount;
    return this;
}
```